# What is required to show an interrupt number in /proc/interrupts?

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded-linux

This question is referring to embedded linux. I undrstand to see the interrupts running one should do `cat /proc/interrupts`. I undestand that an interrupt has to be there to show, the questions is what are the steps  required or involved so that interrupts are shown in that directory. I am specifically interested for interrupts generated by hardware, for  example, DMA.

Comment: When interrupt happens, increment the counter.  When proc file is read, show the counter.

Comment: @stark, The expected interrupt is not there. That is the problem. The problem is related to   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77449384/two-interrupts-are-defined-in-system-user-dtsi-file-but-why-only-one-interrupt-i

Comment: Are you calling the generic functions described in the doc?  https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/Documentation/core-api/genericirq.rst

Comment: @stark Thank you for the reference, I will go through it. But I am not trying to use anything like that. I simple used Petalinux to install Linux into a Zynq 7000 board and tried to run a application through VITIS. The FPGA desing is to transfer data between PS and PL using DMA.  But I have noticed that I have only MM2S interrupt not S2MM interrupt in the /proc/interrupts. So Iasked this question to understand the problem.

Comment: _/proc/interrupts_ lists the registered handlers, if there is none, no line will be there (Linux IRQ number, OTOH, can be (pre)allocated).